# Condition on the minimality of Minkowski units

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, lattices, computational-number-theory

I am interested in to undrestand when the Minkowski units in real biquadratic number fields are minimal in the log unit lattices.
I have read some pieces of literature online which are investigating this question in the case when the number fields are totally real and cyclic and they have a low prime degree or the degree is 4 or 6. I really appreciate it if someone could introduce me some literature or possible approaches to this problem.